# RSpec - Check condition at the time a method is called?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Right now I assert that a method is called:

Code:

```
def MyClass
  def send_report
    ...
    Net::SFTP.start(@host, @username, :password => @password) do |sftp|
      ...
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Test:

```
it 'successfully sends file' do
  Net::SFTP.
    should_receive(:start).
    with('bla.com', 'some_username', :password => 'some_password')

  my_class.send_report
end
```

However, I also want to check that a given condition is true at the time Net::SFTP.start is called. How would I do something like this?

```
it 'successfully sends file' do
  Net::SFTP.
    should_receive(:start).
    with('bla.com', 'some_username', :password => 'some_password').
    and(<some condition> == true)

  my_class.send_report
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a block to `should_receive`, which will execute at the time the method is called:

```
it 'sends a file with the correct arguments' do
  Net::SFTP.should_receive(:start) do |url, username, options|
    url.should == 'bla.com'
    username.should == 'some_username'
    options[:password].should == 'some_password'
    <some condition>.should be_true
  end

  my_class.send_report
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use expect

```
it 'successfully sends file' do

Net::SFTP.
    should_receive(:start).
    with('bla.com', 'some_username', :password => 'some_password')

  my_class.send_report
end

it 'should verify the condition also' do
  expect{ Net::SFTP.start(**your params**)  }to change(Thing, :status).from(0).to(1)  
end
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: you want to check the condition you can do it in a separate spec as i give the example above

Comment: You assume that condition has something to do with SFTP's state. I understand that this is not necessarily so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rickyrickyrice, your answer was *almost* correct. The problem is that it doesn't validate the correct number of arguments passed to `Net::SFTP.start`. Here's what I ended up using:

```
it 'sends a file with the correct arguments' do
  Net::SFTP.should_receive(:start).with('bla.com', 'some_username', :password => 'some_password') do
    <some condition>.should be_true
  end

  my_class.send_report
end
```